# Dropdown menu select() not working Laravel Dusk

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, testing, laravel-dusk

I'm having issues selecting an option in a dropdown menu. I've checked the documentation and I found this :

[image: from doc]

Here is my code :

```
$browser
        ->visit('/my-slug')

        //version from the doc ==> not working
        ->select('Choose your type', 'visitor)

        //version with the name attribute ==> not working
        ->select('User[type]', 'visitor')
        ;
```

When I choose the user type there is another form appearing on the screen so I can write my personal infos.

Do you have any idea?

**EDIT:** As asked the HTML code
[image: html code]

Comment: Please show HTML of the select element including options.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the HTML code.

Comment: The style of select is  "display : none", it means not visible on page, so you can not operate it from page UI.  I think your select is not a native dropdown, but a simulated dropdown by css, So please give more HTML.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/XdHgo)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative solution. I decided to remove a particular attribute which was **`search dropdown-after`** and **`ui search-dropdown`**. Now I can access the `User[type]` with :

```
$browse -> select('user[type]','Type_1');
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `name` attribute to the select element:

```
name="my-select"
```

Then you can select it with"

```
->select('my-select', 'some option value')
```

Comment: Would you please give a look to the screenshot I added because there's already an attribute which should work.

Comment: @user5482698 use name and value as I've shown in my answer `->select('User[type]', 'user_type1')`

Comment: It still doesn't work even if the command line `php artisan dusk` says _OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!_

Comment: @user5482698 try to use a name like `user_type`. Also, how exactly do you know if it doesn't work?

Comment: I can't change it because I'm working on a project. This is not a personnal project.